# Do variable selection methods change based on the type of response variable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model-selection

The diagnostic tests for different models would be different, but how would the variable selection change?

For instance, how much different is it to fit a Poisson regression model versus a logistic regression? It seems like forward, backward, and stepwise processes would be about the same for both (though it seems the validity of these methods is contested).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable selection vs Model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205902/variable-selection-vs-model-selection)