# Is there an algorithm to determine what type of prediction function to use in linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear-model, linear

I recently started learning machine-learning and just learned the basics of linear regression.

So gradient descent and other optimization algorithms can be used to find the values of θ in the hypothesis hθ(x) = θ0x0 + θ1x1 + ... + θnxn

But is there any way to figure out whether the hypothesis function should be a polynomial or other types of functions like hθ(x) = θ0x0 + θ1x1 + θ2x12

I know that if I graph the sample data for a model that has one or two features I can see if a polynomial function would predict the graph better, but what if there were more than 2 features? How would I go about determining what kind of function to use?

Comment: You are really asking about some kind of automatic model selection (or variable selection). There is already a lot of posts about that on this site, for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264600/what-exactly-is-stepwise-model-selection, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205902/variable-selection-vs-model-selection

Comment: Oh, Model selection! Thanks

Comment: Please do not delete your posts, we generally want duplicate posts to remain as they can be helpful for others doing search!